# What would the best tag be for a question regarding the game 'Nox'?

Tags: support, allowed-questions

My friends occasionally get together and play a couple rounds of [Nox](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nox_%28video_game%29), a very old Diablo-esque game made in 2000.

[image]

If I wanted to ask a question about this game in hopes that it would miraculously get an answer, what would be the best tag to put it under? I certainly don't think a 13-year old game deserves its own tag. Would it be best under backwards-compatibility, or would a game this age be considered off-topic?

Comment: We have tags for games from Commodore 64 days, I believe.  If those are allowed, I don't see why a game from the turn of the centure wouldn't be.

Comment: Diablo itself is even older and we have a tag for it.

Comment: Nox was an awesome game.  I'd gladly dredge up my old copy to replay it if there was an interesting question about it.

Comment: I was afraid of the same stuff when I asked a few questions about Havest Moon 2 (1999)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It's certainly on-topic. Just tag it [nox](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/nox).

Comment: Awesome, thanks. I'll be honest and say that I feel kind of funny asking the very first question on a game that's 13 years old :)

Comment: @Gigazelle - I asked the first question about [desert strike](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/121478/is-it-possible-to-stop-the-madman-from-escaping-his-yacht) a month ago. It was made in 1991 :). There's also been questions about the Commodore 64 and other old games & platforms. Never feel bad about bringing questions about old games, you never know who will come along and answer :)